# grep multiple patterns from a file and save them into different files

Tags: linux, bash, grep

Hi I have an mpd which has the following information

```
<BaseURL>01/</BaseURL>
                                <SegmentList timescale="1000">
                                        <SegmentTimeline>
                                                <S t="0" d="11477" dtv:lastVideoPTS="1126034"/>
                                                <S t="11477" d="11111" dtv:lastVideoPTS="2126033"/>
                                                <S t="22588" d="11200" dtv:lastVideoPTS="3132038"/>
                                                <S t="33789" d="11422" dtv:lastVideoPTS="4162067"/>
                                                <S t="45211" d="11711" dtv:lastVideoPTS="5219123"/>
                                                <S t="56923" d="11177" dtv:lastVideoPTS="6222125"/>
                                                <S t="68101" d="11478" dtv:lastVideoPTS="7252154"/>
 </SegmentTimeline>
                                        <SegmentURL media="1.ts" mediaRange="0-3424419"/>
                                        <SegmentURL media="2.ts" mediaRange="0-8063319"/>
                                        <SegmentURL media="3.ts" mediaRange="0-7146631"/>
                                        <SegmentURL media="4.ts" mediaRange="0-8984143"/>
                                        <SegmentURL media="5.ts" mediaRange="0-7496499"/>
                                        <SegmentURL media="6.ts" mediaRange="0-10445091"/>
                                        <SegmentURL media="7.ts" mediaRange="0-8854423"/>
</SegmentList>
                        </Representation>
                        <Representation id="02" bandwidth="2066992" width="896" height="720" scanType="progressive">
                                <BaseURL>02/</BaseURL>
                                <SegmentList timescale="1000">
                                        <SegmentTimeline>
                                                <S t="0" d="11477" dtv:lastVideoPTS="1126034"/>
                                                <S t="11477" d="11244" dtv:lastVideoPTS="2135042"/>
                                                <S t="22722" d="11878" dtv:lastVideoPTS="3207113"/>
                                                <S t="34600" d="11778" dtv:lastVideoPTS="4270175"/>
                                                <S t="46379" d="11945" dtv:lastVideoPTS="5345249"/>
                                                <S t="58324" d="11945" dtv:lastVideoPTS="6417320"/>
                                                <S t="70270" d="11911" dtv:lastVideoPTS="7489391"/>
                                                <S t="82181" d="11478" dtv:lastVideoPTS="8522423"/>
 </SegmentTimeline>
                                        <SegmentURL media="1.ts" mediaRange="0-1801039"/>
                                        <SegmentURL media="2.ts" mediaRange="0-3065151"/>
                                        <SegmentURL media="3.ts" mediaRange="0-2842747"/>
                                        <SegmentURL media="4.ts" mediaRange="0-3216303"/>
                                        <SegmentURL media="5.ts" mediaRange="0-2798943"/>
                                        <SegmentURL media="6.ts" mediaRange="0-3977891"/>
                                        <SegmentURL media="7.ts" mediaRange="0-3301843"/>
```

I want to grep for base url/01 what are all the segment urls and for base url/02 what are all the segment urls can you please help as I am new to scripting...

The desired output I am looking for is for base url/01 saved into a different file and the same for base url/02

```
<BaseURL>01/</BaseURL>
<SegmentURL media="1.ts" mediaRange="0-3424419"/>
                                        <SegmentURL media="2.ts" mediaRange="0-8063319"/>
                                        <SegmentURL media="3.ts" mediaRange="0-7146631"/>
                                        <SegmentURL media="4.ts" mediaRange="0-8984143"/>
                                        <SegmentURL media="5.ts" mediaRange="0-7496499"/>
                                        <SegmentURL media="6.ts" mediaRange="0-10445091"/>
                                        <SegmentURL media="7.ts" mediaRange="0-8854423"/>
```

Comment: Please add your desired output for that sample input to your **question**.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you the use of **xml2** (http://www.ofb.net/~egnor/xml2/)
to transform the xml to something grep-able.

Unfortunately the xml you posted seems broken to me, please update the question.

Answer (score 0):

Untested but will be very close:

```
awk '/<BaseURL>/{close(out); out="out"++c} {print > out}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this - it writes all `<SegmentURL>` elements following a `<BaseURL>` element to a file named segment.basevalue - so segment.01 segment.02 etc

```
awk '
# start writing to new segment file segment.01 etc
match($0, /<BaseURL>([0-9]+)\/<\/BaseURL>/, m) {
  base=m[1]
  close(segf)
  segf="segment." base
  print "write segments to " segf
  print >segf
}
/<SegmentURL / {print >segf}
END {close(segf)}
'
```

Comment: It works can this extend to running the same command on multiple mpd files

Comment: Yes - it reads stdin - so any amount of data can be streamed e.g. cat *.mpd|awk ... - I don't follow about it not working on a shell script - can you provide the usage and error?

Comment: curl -O mpd "http://example.com/a/b/c.mpd"
awk '
# start writing to new segment file segment.01 etc
match($0, /<BaseURL>([0-9]+)\/<\/BaseURL>/, m) {
  base=m[1]
  close(segf)
  segf="segment." base
  print "write segments to " segf
  print >segf
}
/<SegmentURL / {print >segf}
END {close(segf)}
' mpd
grep -Po '"\K[^"]*\.ts' segment.01 > 01
grep -Po '"\K[^"]*\.ts' segment.02 > 02
xargs -I{} curl 'http://example.com/a/b/01/{}' <segment.01
xargs -I{} curl 'http://example.com/a/b/02/{}' <segment.02  shell script to pull the mpd and parse it and dwnld individual ts file using /01,/02